# Parameter not being passed from Python to php

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

**What I am trying to do**

I am new to python and intended to do something to start where I pass a parameter to my database from my python app> to php THEN to the database.

**What I have done**

I have my php API that accepts a parameter and populates the database (that works fine in the browser).
I have also attempted code on my raspberry pi to call that url and pass the parameter.

**Problem.**

Problem is, I am not sure what error that I have, since I have corrected all errors that was displayed yet when I execute the command, nothing is populated in the database.
Below is one of the code examples I have used. Would love if I could get assistance to send my parameter to my url.

Thank you

```
import urllib2
import urllib
data = [('par','1')]
data = urllib.urlencode(data)
path='http://myserver.com/uploadLoc.php'
req=urllib2.Request(path, data)
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
page=urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

Comment: Good question formatting. Tell us what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what problem you're running into. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to be that guy, but the [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) really is your friend. It will greatly simplify what you're trying to post here. Here's an example similar to what is in the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

```
import requests
payload = {'par': 1}
r = requests.post("http://myserver.com/uploadLoc.php", data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

EDIT:
Didn't see you were on Raspberry Pi. If you're using Raspbian, you can install Requests using `apt`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-requests
```

As mentioned in the comment below, the normal way you would install it is with `pip`:

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: I would use pip to install python packages

Comment: Thanks for giving me this new way to do this, but briefly, except that...how would you pass the parameter as a string

Comment: @Niana Requests handles that for you, it url encodes your payload as a string and passes it the POST. The actual request as a GET request would look like this: http://myserver.com/uploadLoc.php?par=1

Comment: Sadly nothing is saved when i use "1" or '1' it works with just 1 thou. (I have a _POST in my api)

Comment: @Niana What do you mean it works with 1 thou? You mean the integer 1000?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that everything gets converted to a string when it is url encoded. Without seeing your actual response, my guess is you need to handle the specific type conversion you need on the PHP side. There's more information available here on passing parameters in urls: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105738/discussion-between-niana-and-dan-gayle).